# Expo splash screen or white screen after standalone apk is installed

Tags: react-native, expo

I know this question has been asked several times but nowhere i found the answer. So I thought I will elaborate my question. Everything works fine in development. But when I make the standalone APK the splash screen doesn't goes away. I even tried to hide it after the component is loaded. That also doesn't work.  What could be the issue ?

```
import { SplashScreen } from 'expo';


 componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      SplashScreen.hide();
    },2000);
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 0):

try it:
create a screen: SplashScreen.js
and write the code bellow:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar, Image } from 'react-native';
import introImage from '../assets/IntroPin3.gif';

export default class Loading extends Component {

render() {

return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', backgroundColor: '#FDFDFF' }}>
  <StatusBar hidden />
    <Image
    style={{height:350, width: 350 }}
    source={ introImage}
   />
  </View>
  );
 }
}
```

and in your app.js
write it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SplashScreen from './Components/SplashScreen.js';
import Intro from './Components/Menu.js';


export default class Index extends Component {
state = {
ready: false,
};
 componentDidMount() {
 setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({ ready: true });
}, 5530);
}

render() {
if (this.state.ready === false) {
  return <SplashScreen />;
 }
  return <Intro />;
 }
}
```

try it, if this help you let me know.

Comment: I don't need Splash screen at all. I want to totally disable it. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'

export default class WelcomePage extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    // do stuff while splash screen is shown
    // After having done stuff (such as async tasks) hide the splash screen
    SplashScreen.hide();
 }
}
```

try this one... also you can read the documentation:
https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen